# Magento 1.9 pages not loading without index.php

Tags: ssl, magento-1.9

When I enable ssl on the website the pages won't load without index.php in the url. I have set `Use Web Server Rewrites`, `Use Secure URLs in Frontend`, and `Use Secure URLs in Admin` to `Yes`. `Offloader header` is set to `SSL_OFFLOADED`. I have cleared the cache on the website and my browser. I have checked phpinfo() and `mod_rewrite` is enabled. The secure and unsecure url both have `https://`. I have also replaced the .htaccess file with a fresh copy and it different make any difference.

That is what I have tried from various posts on Stackoverflow and I am unsure what to try next.

Comment: please show htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache or Nginx? Nginx does not read/use the .htaccess file. You need to use something like this in Nginx config:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
   expires 14d;
  log_not_found off;
}

location / {
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}
location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

location /var/export/ { 
  auth_basic           'Restricted'; 
  auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; 
  autoindex            on;
}

location  /. { 
  return 404;
}

location ~ .php/ {
   rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

location /lib/minify/ {
  allow all;
}
```